# UPS minimum shipping weight not being used correctly

Tags: shipping, ce-1.8.1.0, ups

According to the [CE documentation](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/content/shipping/ups.html) for the UPS shipping method, the *Minimum Package Weight* indicates that for total order weights below this amount, the shipping option becomes unavailable.

However, I found that setting the minimum weight does **not** behave that way. After looking at the UPS carrier model, I found this method:

```
# Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups::_getCorrectWeight
protected function _getCorrectWeight($weight)
{
    $minWeight = $this->getConfigData('min_package_weight');

    if($weight < $minWeight){
        $weight = $minWeight;
    }

    //rounds a number to one significant figure
    $weight = ceil($weight*10) / 10;

    return $weight;
}
```

So clearly the weight is adjusted to meet the minimum, and nowhere else in the model do I find the weight being checked against the minimum. I'm guessing the documentation is wrong?

I can extend the model to meet my needs, but I'm concerned about collateral damage in other places that I can't think of. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the documentation makes reference to:

"Check with your shipping carrier to verify the minimum weight."

I'm assuming this parameter varies, or is outdated, and the minimum weight is not set in stone. UPS mentions no minimum, but makes specific reference to a maximum: http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/sri/sze2.html

So, yes, I would say the documentation is not thorough, although technically correct.

Comment: Yes, that ambiguous line had me worried, too :) I'm guessing there are classes of shipping service offered on a per-merchant basis which might dictate a minimum. I'm gonna sit on this for a while as I dig some more and give more opportunity for other answers. Thanks for the input and reference Tim.